# "Shakespearean English" - What English or American writers have adjectives coined after their names?

Tags: adjectives, neologisms

> Shake·spear·ean - adjective \shāk-ˈspir-ē-ən: of or relating to William Shakespeare or his writings.

Almost every English speaking person has heard or read something about Shakespearean English. That adjective is perhaps the most frequently used of its kind.  I once came across an adjective related to Shaw's writing, but I can't remember or find it. Are there other adjectives in current usage related to writers other than William Shakespeare?

Comment: Well, there's [Gonzo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonzo_journalism), the journalist.

Comment: Faulknerian, Hemminwayesque, Twainian.  Shaw is *Shavian*

Comment: Dickensian. Randian.

Comment: Orwellian.  Kafkaesque.

Comment: Runyonesque, Stengelese?

Comment: Blytonian, Archerian, Seussesque, Franciscan, Camuesque, Bagleyesque, Reichsesque, Davisesque ... though some of these seem to have been used, some are bordering on the grotesque.

Comment: Another one is: *Lovecraftian*.

Comment: We can actually broaden the category a little and ask about eponymously-deriverd nouns as well, and not just related to writers. I'm thinking of "Thatcherite" and "Thatcherism", which are both well-worn nouns, but I am not familiar with an equivalent adjective in common use.

Comment: I just remembered one that I use sometimes but didn't occur to me when I posted the question: "machiavellian" (a machiavellian character, a machiavellian plan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of word is an *eponymous adjective*. Wikipedia has a pretty [comprehensive list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_adjectives_in_English) of English eponymous adjectives. (The list includes many [eponyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym) who are not writers, but as most persons worthy of distinction by such an adjective expressed their influence through writing, most on the list are authors of a kind.)

This list includes *Shavian* as relating to Shaw's works or style.

However, these adjectives are coined as necessary, and though Hemingwayesque and Twainian - mentioned in [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194625/shakespearean-english-what-english-or-american-writers-have-adjectives-coine#comment408493_194625) - are rare enough not to show up in this list (nor yet in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twainian%2Chemingwayesque&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), as indicated by an Ngram), they are equally valid terms.

Virtually all eponymous adjectives simply add the *-ian/-an* suffix to the eponym, though *-esque*, *-ic*, and *-ine* also show up (to my ear, those respective suffixes are used indistinguishably in this role). If you're making one up, and you can't find a precedent, either *-esque* or *-ian* should be readily understood.

Comment: What a typical Danielian answer.